# Style elements on different viewports even when simply resizing?

Tags: html, css

I'm admittedly not a fan of CSS and I hate even more responsive layouts but I'm creating an UI with Bootstrap (version 4, for what matters) in which I have some absolutely positioned elements that aren't exactly perfectly aligned as I want, be it in different native resolutions (monitor or VGA-defined) or when simply resizing the *viewport* (i.e.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>).

Since I began to create this UI I'm using `vh` and `vw` units for most elements (except those related to Bootstrap Grid, of course) thinking I wouldn't have such problem and this decision worked quite well for most of scenarios.

However, until now, I was using an old and very small monitor (1366x768) and recently I (finally) acquired a 21.5" monitor (FullHD, if this matters) and these values I've defined in my CSS rules, after exhaustive testings, are now slightly mispositioned, a bit to the left or to the top. For example:

[image: UUID Example]

This is a UUID I use for Unique User Identification in the Application and its positioning and text sizing was defined according to the rules below:

```
#user-identification {
    bottom: 2.05vh;
    font-size: 0.64vw;
    height: 4vh;
    left: 3.05vw;
    width: 15vw;
}
```

As you may have noticed, the blueish background is in fact an image and the text is absolutely positioned on top of it, so I can reuse it for different use cases.

These rules created while developing in the small monitor where enough to center the text in the box of this background image. But now, in the bigger monitor I took this screenshot, you can see that the text is aligned to the left. It may be difficult to notice, I know, but this is a crop of the bigger picture which, unfortunately, I cannot show more :(

Well, I was about to start fixing all issues based on the big screen, for example, by changing the `left` to `3.4vw` instead, but then I realized that if for any reason someone accessing the website is under the same situation I was before, the user experience would be prejudiced.

The first solution that came to me was to use Media Queries but I don't know the values I should be using to create the rules.

Worse! Regarding the *viewport* resizing, Firefox goes 10% by 10% while Chrome has a wider range (25%, 33%, 50% 67%...) and other browsers may have other values. And because I'm not a specialist I don't know the values I'm looking for to create the rules.

Can anyone help me?

> Although it would be awesome, it's not my intention to fit the whole UI in the *viewport* of, for example, an iPhone 5 (the smallest I've found on Chrome Developer Tool with 568x320). I just don't want these small icons and texts absolutely positioned to be out of place.

[EDIT]

Describe the scenario in a Fiddle proved harder than I thought, that's why I tried to avoid it. But as asked, [in this one](https://jsfiddle.net/eco8c0ou/1) I've positioned as best as I could and it looked good in the default preview area. But just by resizing it text already goes way out of positioning.

So I made [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/8oqjpzz3/1/embedded), specifically for the embedded version. I believe it would be better as it's close to have the editor in one window and the preview in another (browser).

However, neither of them truly reflects what I really have. although the markup is compatible, both `<img>` and `<span>` inside the `<figure>`, I don't have these drastic changes when resizing the *viewport*. I have only small mispositionings on `bottom` and `left`.

I'm probably not extracting everything I should. I've got most of the Grid where this image (or the bigger, complete version of it) is located. `.box` is not relevant as it's just a few lines with linear and radial gradients and some `box-shadow`.

The whole UI is complex and I may have left something out of these Fiddles, but at least is something visual that shows positioning going wild when resizing (and definitely in different resolutions). My apologies for that.

Comment: Hi, I think it would be useful to set-up a snippet/jFiddle/CodePen to illustrate your problem better, and narrow it down to a specific thing. From what I gather there is not one thing that will solve all of the problems that come with styling your page relying on view port scaling properties of vw/vh. For the structure/grid-layout you are using the bootstrap, but for absolutely positioned elements you just use vw/vh to set their size ... The problem is with contents of absolutely positioned elements not aligning properly?

Comment: I've edited the question with what the Fiddles. IMHO they're a not helpful at all but although visually simple the UI is very complex and I may have not manage to extract everything I should.

Answer (score 0):

This is the root of the problem to my understanding. There is an increase in height of the `<span>` element tied to the height of viewport, so the text container which is the `<span>` element is increased in height at the same time that the position of it via `bottom` and `left` are adjusted using viewport width/height. Removing the height setting of your elements in css, might solve the issues that you are having. Please leave a comment below, if this is not the solution to your question, and we can work together to the solution that fits this case. Thank you.

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  bottom: 3.5vh;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.9vw;
  /* height: 4vh; No need for this line right here. */ 
  left: 1.1vw;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 37vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://nick.mtvnimages.com/nick/promos-thumbs/videos/spongebob-squarepants/rainbow-meme-video/spongebob-rainbow-meme-video-16x9.jpg?quality=0.60" />
  <span>f51bbe1e-7445-4545-bb84-15e614a119a2</span>
</figure>
```

Comment: Well, as much as I can say, yes and no. I've added the `height` because I was still thinking about the positioning like the old days in which we just had to define a `height` and a `width`. I removed everything, readjusted the values for the big screen and it was still working like before, but more consistently I believe, no workarounds. But when I changed my screen resolution two levels down to 1680x1050 the alignment failed and that's the most important part for me: the micro-adjustments for each resolution. I tried a Media Query for 1680px but it didn't work.

Comment: You mentioned that this application of yours has users, would it be feasible for you to share the url of your application, so I can take a better look at what you have? You have used a media-query, can you post your syntax for that? 
This is what I would use: `@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { * { display: block} }`